# Checkout automatically after push

Tags: git

Basically, I just want to use git as sort of a versioned one-way FTP.

I have a local git repo in `local/`. I want to push it to `server:remote/`, and I want that afterwards all files are checked out in `remote` on the server (identically to what it looks locally, assuming I `git-add`ed everything)

In other words, I want to reproduce this behaviour from Mercurial:

```
[hooks]
changegroup.update = hg update && echo updated successfully.
```

I found tons of tutorials that do this with two separate directories on the server side, but I would prefer to use a single one.  Is that possible?  When I try it, I get the message, below which I don't really understand.

What would be the best practice to do this? (If necessary, you can assume I never change anything on the server, so `--force`ing something would not be a problem.)

```
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
```

Comment: I am not sure `git` is the good tool for your need. By default (and this is the content of your alert message) it will refuse to push to a non bare repository where something is already checked out at the same branch because the act of pushing it like that may mean you loose things (you said: assume nothing was changed on the server, but git can not know that). If you want to stick to this model, like the message says, change your configuration and use *ignore*. You may have a simpler life anyway using `rsync`

Comment: Also doing things that way means that on FTP you have the whole git history, in the `.git` subfolder. You may or may not want to restrict that, as by default it would be available from your FTP server. Besides the disk impact.

Comment: Probably the FTP metaphor wasn't the best one. If I did what it seems you think I do, I'd agree that git is bad for this. But it's some configuration files I want to push to the server, no big files. (And I do explicitly want the history.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to reproduce this behaviour from Mercurial:

With *recent* git versions, the setting mentioned in the error message now supports a new value:

```
[receive]
    denyCurrentBranch = updateInstead
```

This should give you exactly the behavior you want.

- http://databio.org/posts/push_to_deploy.html
- https://blog.tfnico.com/2015/05/a-better-way-to-git-push-to-deploy.html

---

> I found tons of tutorials that do this with two separate directories on the server side

As an alternative, you can *still* use most of these tutorials, by pushing to a different *branch* (i.e. not to the currently checked out one, but to something like `deploy`).

```
git push origin master:deploy
```

Now you can use similar (or even the same) `post-receive` or `post-update` hooks as if you were pushing to a bare repository. For example, the hook could run `git merge --ff-only deploy` or even `git reset --hard deploy`.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, thanks! The first link is great and also explains valid usecases for this. Seems I should have included _deploying_ when searching :)

Answer (score 0):

Before first commit into remote repo to avoid `error: refusing to update` I forced to do:

```
git config receive.denycurrentbranch ignore
```

To enable auto checkout it is enought to set

```
git config receive.denycurrentbranch updateInstead
```